# Add int each time button is clicked using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to add 1 to label content each time button is clicked, but i need to do it in it's own class (it has to be iron mining, when mining have it's own class).

```
public class Mining
{
    public static int iron = 0;
    public void mine_iron_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        iron++;
        label.Content = Convert.ToString(iron);
    }
}
```

When i use this code in Mining class, it gives me an error saying that label don't exists in current content. How can I make label reachable from this class? I tought that I use MVVM, any ideas how to implement this simple code in MVVM pattern?

Comment: You don't access the label from the class, you *bind* the label's `Content` to a view model *property* that raises change notifications.  This is pretty basic MVVM, so I'd suggest finding some tutorials or similar.

Comment: This sounds like a college assignment. It looks like you're trying to change the UI directly, which you shouldn't do in MVVM. Based on this small snippet of code, it looks like you have larger misunderstanding of how to create ViewModel properties and bind them in the UI, but that's difficult to address in a SO question. I'd recommend reading through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx to make sure you understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mining  mining =new mining(passlablelhere);

var lbl = "";
Public Mining(string labelfromview)  
{
    lbl =labelfromview;//here you  can perform the logic
}
```

Comment: Not much use for changing the label content, and it's not MVVM either.

Answer (score 0):

First implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then bind the Iron property to iron

```
public class Mining : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static int _iron
    public int iron
    {
        get { return _iron; }
        set
        {
            _iron = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("iron");
        }
    }
    public void mine_iron_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        iron++;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string Name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the datacontext of an ancestor is mining, then add the label to your xaml.

```
<Label Content="{Binding iron}" />
```